# Flutter VideoPlayerController.file does not initialize

Tags: flutter, video-player

i'm trying to get videoplayercontroller.file to work, but i don't finish the initialization.
Without giving me any error messages.
Help would be welcome.

```
    print("Start download");
final ByteData imageData = await NetworkAssetBundle(Uri.parse(
        "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...."))
    .load("");
final bytes = imageData.buffer.asUint8List();
var file = File.fromRawPath(bytes);
print("Done!");
_controller =
    VideoPlayerController.file(file);
await _controller.initialize();  // <== hangs at this point
print("End");
return "End";
```

in the debug console:

flutter: Start download
flutter: Done!